# Как задать onclick кнопкам в балуне в react-yandex-map

Tags: reactjs, яндекс-карты

Кажется, что вопрос уже избитый, но все же. Не отрабатывает oncliсk на кнопках. Если делаю не через ObjectManager, а через Clusterer, то onclick отрабатывает, но при переключении кластеров точки рисуются вечность, чего быть не должно.
Буду признателен за помощь.

```
const MapWrapper = (props) => {
const dispatch = useDispatch();

window.balloonButtonClickHandler = (index) => {
    props.setCurrentPoint(createCollection().features[index])
};

const Balloon = (el,index) => {
    let balloon = ``;
    const {subway, time, address, timeLabel, title} = el;
    switch (props.currentServiceToGetOrder.id){
        case "pn":
            balloon = `
                <ul>
                    <li>${title}</li>
                    <li><b>${timeLabel}</b></li>
                    <li>${address}</li>
                    <li>${time}</li>
                </ul>
                <input type="button" onclick={window.balloonButtonClickHandler(${index})} value="Забрать бесплатно"/>
        
            `
            return balloon;
        case "pochta":
        case "SdekAll":
        case "pp":
            balloon = `
                <ul>
                    <li>${timeLabel}</li>
                    <li><b>${address}</b></li>
                    <li><b>${title}</b></li>
                    <li>${time}</li>
                </ul>
                 <input type="button" onclick={window.balloonButtonClickHandler(${index})} value="Выбрать"/>
            `
            return balloon;
    }
}

const createCollection = () => {
    let points = {};
    let servicesArr = props.deliveries.filter((service, idx) => {
        if(service.type === "pickup") {
            return service;
        }
    });

    servicesArr.forEach((el) => {
        points[`${el.id}`] = {
            type:"FeatureCollection",
            features: el.locations,
        }
    })

    const result = {};
    if (typeof points[`${props.currentServiceToGetOrder.id}`] !== "undefined") {
        result.type = points[`${props.currentServiceToGetOrder.id}`].type;

        const features = points[`${props.currentServiceToGetOrder.id}`].features.map((el) => {
            let point = el;
            point.geometry = {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [el.lat, el.lon],

            }
            point.properties = {}
            point.properties.balloonContentBody = `${Balloon(el)}`;

            return point
        })
        result.features = features;
    }
    return result
}



return (
     createCollection().hasOwnProperty("features") ?
    <Line >
        <YMaps >
            <Map onLoad={
                ()=>{dispatch(setLoader(false))}
            }
                defaultState={{
                    center: [props.currentCity.lat, props.currentCity.lon],
                    zoom: 9,
                }}
                 modules={[
                     'templateLayoutFactory',
                     'geoObject.addon.balloon',
                     'clusterer.addon.balloon',
                 ]}
                style={{width:"100%", height:"300px"}}
            >

                <ObjectManager
                    options={{
                        clusterize: true,
                        gridSize: 32,
                    }}
                    objects={{
                        openBalloonOnClick: true,
                        preset: 'islands#greenDotIcon',

                    }}
                    clusters={{
                        preset: 'islands#redClusterIcons'
                    }}

                    features={createCollection().features}
                    modules={['objectManager.addon.objectsBalloon']}
                >
                </ObjectManager>


                {/*<Clusterer*/}
                {/*    options={{*/}
                {/*        preset: "islands#invertedVioletClusterIcons",*/}
                {/*    }}>*/}
                {/*    {*/}
                {/*        createCollection().features.map((point, index) => {*/}

                {/*            return <Placemark*/}
                {/*                modules={[ //чтобы видеть хинты и балуны подключаем данные модули*/}
                {/*                    'objectManager.addon.objectsBalloon',*/}
                {/*                    'objectManager.addon.objectsHint',*/}
                {/*                ]}*/}
                {/*                key={index}*/}
                {/*                geometry={point.geometry.coordinates}*/}
                {/*                properties={{*/}
                {/*                    balloonContentFooter:`*/}
                {/*                        ${Balloon(point, index)}*/}
                {/*                       `*/}
                {/*                }}*/}
                {/*                options={{*/}
                {/*                    iconLayout: 'default#image',*/}
                {/*                }}*/}
                {/*            />*/}

                {/*        })*/}
                {/*    }*/}
                {/*</Clusterer>*/}
            </Map>
        </YMaps>
    </Line>
        :
        null
)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать [фабрику шаблонов yandex.maps](https://yandex.com/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_balloon_layout/), чтобы создать собственный макет балуна и добавить в него свои события.

Надеюсь, это ответит на ваш вопрос.

Comment: спасибо за помощь) я чет не заметил, но я забыл передать idx в Balloon(el, <тут должен был быть id элемента>). передал и все заработало

Answer (score 0):

оказалось, я забыл передать idx в Balloon(el, <тут должен был быть id элемента>). передал и все заработало.